# Html table rendering

Tags: django, templates, tagging

My Django view is returning a list of dictionaries. This goes to html table through template rendering. Below is my template code,

My list of dictionary looks like below,

Results :

```
[{ 'name':'x','age': 20}, {'name': 'y','age': 25 }]

<table class="table table-striped" border="1" class="dataframe"> 
    <thead>
     <tr style="text-align: center;">
     {% for k, v in results.0.items %} 
      <th>{{ k }}</th> 
     {% endfor %}
     </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
       {% for x in results %} 
         <tr style="text-align: center;">
         {% for y in x %}
          <td> {{ x.y }} </td> 
         {% endfor %} 
         </tr> 
       {% endfor %} 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Expected output:

```
name     age
x        20
y        25
```

But the output is blank.

Please let me know if there is anything wrong with my HTML table template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `items` properly in your inner loop just like the outer loop

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped" border="1" class="dataframe">
        <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            {% for k, v in results.0.items %}
            <th>{{ k }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for x in results %}

        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            {% for i,j in x.items %}
            <td> {{ j }} </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```